# How to avoid cross-request state pollution problems when using vite for server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, vite

In the production environment I can use node:vm to implement a sandbox to avoid cross-request state pollution but the development environment is to call vite.ssrLoadModule and pass in the server-side entry file to implement the development environment server-side rendering server I can't find an effective way to implement a sandbox or something like that to avoid cross-request state pollution Does vite provide an api or an effective way to deal with this issue?